# nleqslv memory use in R

Tags: r

I am having issues with iterations over nleqslv in R, in that the solver does not appear to clean up memory used in previous iterations.  I've isolated the issue in a small sample of code:

```
library(nleqslv)

cons_ext_test <- function(x){
rows_x <- length(x)/2
x_1 <- x[1:rows_x]
x_2 <- x[(rows_x+1):(rows_x*2)]
eq1<- x_1-100 
eq2<-x_2*10-40
return(c(eq1,eq2))
}

model_test <- function()
{
reserves<-(c(0:200)/200)^(2)*2000
lambda <- numeric(NROW(reserves))+5
res_ext <- pmin((reserves*.5),5)
x_test <- c(res_ext,lambda)
#print(x_test)
for(test_iter in c(1:1000))
   nleqslv(x_test,cons_ext_test,jacobian=NULL)
i<- sort( sapply(ls(),function(x){object.size(get(x))})) 
print(i[(NROW(i)-5):NROW(i)])
}

model_test()
```

When I run this over 1000 iterations, memory use ramps up to over 2 GB:
[image: Activity Monitor Screencap]
While running it with 10 iterations uses far less memory, only 92MB:
[image: Activity Monitor Screencap 2]
Running it once has my rsession with 62Mb of use, so growth in memory allocation scales with iterations.

Even after 1000 iterations, with 2+ GB of memory used by the R session, no large-sized objects are listed.

```
test_iter    lambda   res_ext  reserves    x_test 
       48      1648      1648      1648      3256
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

AJL

Comment: Should also mention that I can replicate this on a Mac, a Windows desktop and a Surface Pro.

Comment: Good catch. Even when assigning the result of the call to `nleqslv`, removing it and then calling the garbage collector, doesn't solve the issue. Calling the garbage collector after `model_test()` finished, does though. So I'm not sure `nleqslv` itself is the problem. R is notorious for its liberal use of memory. If you check `memory.profile()` you'll notice it is R reserving memory. The memory itself isn't filled. Before running `gc()`, there's about 770Mb actually used, the rest of the 2.4 Gb is just reserved.

Comment: Thanks!  I dropped pryr into my code, and you can certainly see the memory use rising.  GC() doesn't clean it up though, only an R restart seems to do it.

Comment: This is typically something you should have mailed the maintainer about. I doubt that `nleqslv` is to blame. The fortran code does not allocate memory. The encapsulating C code does and is quite careful about freeing memory. I will try to find out if `nleqslv` is to blame and if something has to be changed.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.  It may be a package interaction or something since colleagues on the same OS do not seem to have the same issue.

Comment: @Bhas I think too that this is more a consequence of how R deals with memory than anything else, but I'll check further.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If `gc()` (small letters) is not cleaning it up, then it might be a memory leak in the package itself. But that would seriously surprise me.

Comment: @Joris Meys: AndrewLeach has already contacted me and I have reproduced the issue with a small example. I'm not completely sure yet but I think that the default JIT level causes this. Using JIT level 0 seems to solve the problem. I'm waiting for a reply from Andrew. If it is the default JIT level then it may be a bug in R. Which can be reported.

Comment: @Bhas Yes, confirmed that the compiler fix seems to solve the problem. There seems to be a bit of a speed penalty, although I haven't fully tested that yet.  Thanks to you both for attention to this.

Comment: @Joris Meys: The problem was a bug in the JIT executive. Problem has been solved as of R-3.4.-patched r72789.

Comment: @Bhas I've noticed on R-devel, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is confirmed to be a bug in R, which is solved in R-devel (r72788) and R-patched release (r72789). See also https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-June/074430.html